# Is there a function to configure an HttpClient from appsettings?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm looking to configure an `HttpClient` in Startup.cs.  In the past I put everything in configuration and referenced it in Startup without having to do something like:

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = configuration.Get("Client:BaseAddress")
```

Are there any functions or nuget packages that will allow me to just do something like `HttpClient.Configure("Client")` and have it pick all the settings up?

Comment: You don't need any. appsettings.json is just one configuration source. .NET Core works with the Configuration middleware, not the individual sources. When you use [AddHttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to register HttpClient with the DI middleware you can use any configuration settings, no matter the source, to configure HttpClient in any way you want

Comment: `without having to do something like` why?

Comment: So I am guessing you are asking of some way to serialize everything needed for an http request in a file.. Anything is possible in the big city, however just because you can doesn't mean you should. There are standard patterns for using HttpClient, they are simple to plumb up and understand, very reusable, and some of these concerns can certainly be stored in a config file (and use standard configuration techniques) . I would consider these approaches before trying to serialize a complete request

Comment: I think he just want's to reduce the lines of configuration in the startup and just have a configuration block with all properties that is then applied automatically. Like e.g. the logging configuration. I just don't think that this exists out of the box.

Comment: Yes, what @Matthias said.  In our code we have a number of lines in the configuration, and then a number of lines in the startup to map them all.  I was just thinking if there was a way to avoid the configuration in startup so i don't have to plumb it all together

Comment: If you need it multiple times you could write a small helper. But if its just once for those few properties I wouldn't sweat it.